# SQL query/trigger with referenced values

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, metadata

First timer here.  I'm working on a SQL trigger and need to find a way to reference a value based off a work order number.  Here's what the data looks like:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DoQk.png)

Here's what I've got so far,

```
CURSOR C1 (insSpoolID IN CHAR) IS
select substr(data_valuestring,8) from E2S_SPOOLERDATA
where SPOOL_ID = insSpoolID AND DATA_VALUESTRING LIKE '!WO_NB!%%' ESCAPE '!';

CURSOR C2 (insSpoolID IN CHAR) IS
select substr(data_valuestring,14) from E2S_SPOOLERDATA
where SPOOL_ID = insSpoolID AND DATA_VALUESTRING LIKE '!PRODUCTCODE!%%' ESCAPE '!';

CURSOR C3 (insSpoolID IN CHAR) IS
select substr(data_valuestring,9) from E2S_SPOOLERDATA
where SPOOL_ID = insSpoolID AND DATA_VALUESTRING LIKE '!CONTNO!%%' ESCAPE '!';

CURSOR C4 (insSpoolID IN CHAR) IS
select substr(data_valuestring,8) from E2S_SPOOLERDATA
where SPOOL_ID = insSpoolID AND DATA_VALUESTRING LIKE '!BAGNO!%%' ESCAPE '!';

CURSOR C5 (insSpoolID IN CHAR) IS
select substr(data_valuestring,12) from E2S_SPOOLERDATA
where SPOOL_ID = insSpoolID AND DATA_VALUESTRING LIKE '!CONTAINER!%%' ESCAPE '!';

CURSOR C6 (insSpoolID IN CHAR) IS
select substr(data_valuestring,8) from E2S_SPOOLERDATA
where SPOOL_ID = insSpoolID AND DATA_VALUESTRING LIKE '!BATCH!%%' ESCAPE '!';

CURSOR C7 (insSpoolID IN CHAR) IS
select substr(data_valuestring,7) from E2S_SPOOLERDATA
where SPOOL_ID = insSpoolID AND DATA_VALUESTRING LIKE '!ITEM!%%' ESCAPE '!';

BEGIN
If :new.SPOOL_STATUS = 'S' then

   sSpoolID:= :new.spool_id;
   sDCMTCode:= :new.DCMT_CODE;


If sDCMTCode like '%VARPESEE%' then
     OPEN C1(sSpoolID);
     OPEN C2(sSpoolID);
     OPEN C3(sSpoolID);
     OPEN C4(sSpoolID);
     FETCH C1 INTO sWONb;
     FETCH C2 INTO sProductCode;
     FETCH C3 INTO sContNo;
     Fetch C7 INTO sItem;

**Get CONTAINERS_NB value, output to sCont_Total_Number:=TotalCont**

Insert into SPOOLERDATA (SPOOL_ID,SPOOL_INDEX,SPOOL_STATUS,DATA_TABLE,DATA_ROW,DATA_COLUMN,DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH,DATA_VALUENUMBER,DATA_VALUEDATE,DATA_VALUESTRING) values (sSpoolID,'999','S','ROW','999','VALUE','VARCHAR2','250','0',null,'%CONT_PRINT_NUMBER_TOTAL%' || sCont_Total_Number);
     end if;

END IF;

# Need way to get the data CONTAINERS_NB(see table above, value is 2 in the example) where the work order numbers are matching for the two input variables, WO_NB and ITEM_NB.
```

So I need a query to find the container number, by selecting it from the corresponding METADATASET values that are input from the WO_NB and ITEM_NB entries.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thank you in advance to anyone that offers to help.

I had begun planning to use something like this, but think I might be way off on what is needed.

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(VALUE) FROM E2S_METADATAVALUE_MAN WHERE NAME='WO_NB' 
      AND FK_METADATASET=
             (SELECT FK_METADATASET from E2S_METADATAVALUE_MAN 
                    where NAME='FORMULA_CATEGORY' 
                               AND FK_METADATASET IN 
             (SELECT FK_METADATASET FROM E2S_METADATAVALUE_MAN 
                    where dbms_lob.instr (Value,insC1WO) >0));
```

Comment: Do not post images of data. Instead, [edit] your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and the expected output as text (formatted using a markdown).

Comment: I tried that, but the data came out looking wrong, the spacing got messed up.

Comment: As I said, use markdown formatting (put the code into a code block by using three backticks `\`\`\`` on a otherwise empty line before and after the code)

Comment: @MT0 Thank you.  Understand now, will do correctly in future.

Answer (score 0):

> So I need a query to find the container number, by selecting it from the corresponding `METADATASET` values that are input from the `WO_NB` and `ITEM_NB` entries.

What you are trying to do with cursors is difficult to comprehend.

You appear to just need a `PIVOT` and then to filter the output:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX(value)
  FOR (name) IN (
    'WO_NB' AS wo_nb,
    'ITEM_NB' AS item_nb,
    'CONTAINERS_NB' AS containers_nb
  )
)
WHERE  wo_nb   = v_the_wo_nb_you_are_trying_to_match
AND    item_nb = v_the_item_nb_you_are_trying_to_match
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZCyd2jhe)

Comment: Thank you so much. I tested it and received ORA-00932.  Could I fix this by using TO_CHAR ?

Comment: @StevenSchorn It works for me in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0O_q23J4) linked in the answer. Since you did not provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements in your question, I had to make up the data; you will need to debug things and work you what the difference is between your table(s) and the tables used in the fiddle and where the difference in data-types is that is causing the issue. `TO_CHAR` may solve it but without knowing what your data is it is difficult to say.